# What happens when a File is not created for a file input stream?

Tags: java, android, fileinputstream

What happens when a File is not created for a file input stream? What happens if you want to retrieve a file that hasn't been created yet? Will it be equal to null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get an IOException.  Your best bet is to test `file.exists()` first.  Since it is possible for the file to be deleted between the time you call `file.exists()` and the time you start reading it, you have to handle the exceptional case anyway.